# Making colors of table join together (HTML)

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to get these different colors in the table to join each other, (so there isn't the small gap between them).

```
<!---Content-->

<Center>
    <Table WIDTH = "75%">
        <TR>

            <TD WIDTH = "33%" BGCOLOR = "D Word">
            <Center>
            <P>HI THERE I am heRE n0w</P>
            <IMG SRC = "Images\Cstrike.gif" Width = "200" Height = "200">
            </Center>
            </TD>

            <TD WIDTH = "33%" BGCOLOR = "Blue">
            <Center>
            <P> BLAH Blah bLah Bl0h</P>
            <IMG SRC = "Images\mauser3.gif" Width = "200" Height = "200">
            </Center>
            </TD>

            <TD WIDTH = "33%" BGCOLOR = "Grey">
            <Center>
            <P>ko</P>
            </Center>
            </TD>

        </TR>
    </Table>
</Center>
```

(And also is it possible to have the mini table in grey to join another table above it?)It's just the html code above times 2 (There both the same thing) so the grey one join the grey one above it, any help?

Comment: Why is the color of one your tables the D word?  If you don't want to get in trouble with the mods, you should change that...

Comment: Ah damn, it's just that it came up with a good color

Comment: Your HTML could have some [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) love; formatting should be done using CSS and not deprecated HTML properties.

Comment: Well I'm actualy doing this for my year11 IT class, and were not actually doing CSS at the moment. But thanks for reminding of it!

Comment: If you aren't learning CSS then you shouldn't be learning anything to do with layout or presentation. Learning hacks that were outdated a decade ago before the right way to do something is a very silly idea.

Comment: -1: I agree with Quentin: nobody should be encouraged to use HTML styling when CSS is readily available and can do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `cellspacing="0"`

in `<Table WIDTH = "75%" cellspacing="0">`

Yes, it is possible to have the mini table in grey to join another table above it. You need to provide more details or related HTML.

Comment: if you could help, it's just the html code above times 2 (There both the same thing) so the grey one join the grey one above it?

Comment: Is it possible to have only the grey ones joining?

Comment: Again, yes it can be done but now we are going towards various hacks. Check the updated code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sR6HL/1/). Better to do layout stuff using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Table WIDTH = "75%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

First, consider using [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) instead of deprecated HTML properies.

In CSS, you can remove the spacing between cells applying the `border-collapse: collapse;` property to the table.

### Example

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="first">Blah blah blah</td>
            <td class="second">Blah blah blah</td>
            <td class="third">Blah blah blah</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    border: 1pt solid silver;
    padding: 5pt;
}
.first, .second, .third {
    width: 33%;
}
.first {
    background-color: red;
}
.second{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.third{
    background-color: green;
}
```

See a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YrJqn/).